# Counting records with a specific date value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to get all records entered with specific day, for example today:

[image: My Table]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_QUEUESINFO_BY_DATE]
    @date nvarchar = '2012-09-21'
AS
BEGIN
    declare @dateStart nvarchar(50) = @date + ' 00:00:00.0'
    declare @dateEnd nvarchar(50) = @date + ' 23:59:59.437';
    declare @returnData table (allQueue int,inQueue int,outQueue int)

    SELECT 'table1' as table_name, COUNT(*) 
    FROM   Queue as Counts

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'table2' as table_name,COUNT(*) FROM Queue as Counts 
    WHERE   QueueDate BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd 
    AND     QueueNumIn != 0

END
```

**Edited :** 
I Edited my code now it works :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_QUEUESINFO_BY_DATE]
AS
BEGIN
    declare @date2 datetime
    set @date2= '2012-09-21'

    SELECT 'AllQueue' as table_name, COUNT(*) 
    FROM    Queue as sdfds

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'InQueue' as table_name,COUNT(*) 
    FROM    Queue as sdfds 
    WHERE   QueueDate >=@date2 
    AND     QueueNumIn != 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'OutQueue' as table_name, COUNT(*) FROM  Queue as sdfds 
    WHERE   QueueDate >=@date2 
    AND     QueueNumOut != 0

END
```

It returns three records:
[image: result]

One problem is that the second column has no name. Why? Also, I want to return just one record that has three rows, not 3 separate records that have 2 fields.

Comment: *now it works* You forgot to make `@date2` a parameter, as in your original procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code Worked and is edited code from ElVieejo

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_QUEUESINFO_BY_DATE]
AS
BEGIN
declare @date2 datetime
set @date2= '2012-09-21'
select COUNT(QueueID) ,
sum(case when QueueNumIn != 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as 'InQueue',
sum(case when QueueNumOut != 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as  'OutQueue'
from Queue where QueueDate >= @date2
END
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure why returning all if you only want those in the spetial date.

Also, is better not to use between in Dates

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_QUEUESINFO_BY_DATE]
@date datetime = '2012-09-21'
AS
BEGIN

select count(*) as 'AllQueue' ,
sum(case when QueueDate >=@date and QueueNumIn != 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as 'InQueue',
sum(case when QueueDate >=@date and QueueNumOut != 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as  'OutQueue'
from Queue
END
```

this should work.

this will give you something like

```
Allqueue              inqueue,      outqueue
----------------------------------------------------
    11      |             8        |   10
```

Comment: i defined  table to insert query result into table then return temp table . edit code to perform this action

Comment: but the stored it self, doing a select, is returning the table. No needed. If you are calling it from C#, or from another stored, it will receive the information doing this select, without the temp table

Comment: this one return more that one record,but i want to return one record that contain more filed that contain Result

Comment: this returns two records. If you ONLY want to return the count of records between those two dates, you have to remove the first select and the Union all. As I said, I don't know why you were returning those first. You should write an example of expected data to clarify

Comment: your record HAS 3 rows. Did you mean 3 columns, 1 row ?

Comment: Be careful, I used your query, but what you put now will not show for a day, will show "from this day to actual day". And be careful, and send a datetime, not a nvarchar

Comment: All Done, I used >= in my cod , when i use = or like it return 0 Why ? for one day only i should use 'Between'?

Comment: You can use between but is not so good. Better to use date <nextDay and date > beforeDay. You're gettin 0 because it will compare the hour minutes and second, so it's difficult to get exactly the same value so.

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast your varchar to datetime. and i think you want to assign `Counts` alias to Count(*)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_QUEUESINFO_BY_DATE] 
@date nvarchar = '2012-09-21' 
AS 
BEGIN 
declare @dateStart DATETIME = CAST(@date AS DATETIME) 
declare @dateEnd DATETIME = DATEADD(hh,24,CAST(@date AS DATETIME))
declare @returnData table (allQueue int,inQueue int,outQueue int) 
select 'table1' as table_name,COUNT(*) as Counts  from QUEUE AS tb1 
union all 
select 'table2' as table_name,COUNT(*) as Counts from QUEUE AS tb2  where QueueDate >=  @dateStart  and QueueDate  < @dateEnd and QueueNumIn !=0 
END
```